# Cron entry to pass the value to script

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have a script(main.sh) which calls another script(Get_Files.sh) and gets a value in a variable like the below:

```
File_to_Refresh="$(sh /Aug/work/Get_Files.sh /Aug/Work/Universal_File.txt)"
```

Now I have to schedule the script main.sh for 3 different files i.e. the Universal_File.txt with 3 different values and on 3 different days.

So, to make the script generic, I want to pass the Universal file to Get_Files.sh from the Cron Entry only.

How Can i achieve the same?

Below is working if I run the script manually like 
 sh /Aug/Work/main.sh /Aug/Work/Universal_File.txt but it's not working when i run it through cron.

```
File_to_Refresh="$(sh /Aug/work/Get_Files.sh "$1")"
```

Cron :

```
45 08 * * * sh /Aug/Work/main.sh /Aug/Work/Universal_File.txt
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute main.sh every day, but Get_Files.sh uses each of the 3 files every third day? (so file1, file2, file3 in a 3 day cycle)

Comment: No , I execute main.sh as per the below dates:
monday--( with get_file.sh uses file1)
Wednesday-- (with get_file.sh uses file2)
Friday--( with get_file.sh uses file3)

Comment: Are you attempting to have just one cron entry, or will 3 (one each for mon/wed/fri) do? Is there any reason the script cannot be day-of-week aware and have three different statements depending on which day it is? (Or at least use some logic based on a parameter passed to it to decide which one)

Comment: offcourse , there will be 3 cron entries as i run for different files on 3 days.

Comment: I just want of we can pass the file from cron itself and define something like a $VAR in my script in place of file

Comment: have a look at passing parameter to scripts. Usually `$1` is first argument. If cronjobs are `... main.sh file1`, `... main.sh file2` etc, to reference that in main.sh then `$1` would be `file1` when executed from cron1, `file2` from second cronjob. [possibly relevant post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31414/how-can-i-pass-a-command-line-argument-into-a-shell-script)

Comment: I know that option of $1 but I am not sure if the part of the script sh /Aug/work/Get_Files.sh  $1 will work

Comment: What actually happens when that last cronjob is run? Do you get errors?

Comment: The cron is not invoking the script only...but when i run manually it runs fine

Comment: The permissions are all fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 3 cron entries, 1 for each day (as mentioned in comments), you should be able to specificy the file used for each cron entry as an argument and use `$1` in the main.sh script

```
$ cat main.sh
File_to_Refresh=$(sh sub.sh $1)
echo FileToRefresh: $File_to_Refresh

$ cat sub.sh
echo Sub \$1: $1

$ ./main.sh /Aug/Work/File1.txt
FileToRefresh: Sub $1: /Aug/Work/File1.txt
```

Not convinced you need the `"` marks around the $(xxx), it seems to work both ways for me.

Comment: Thanks Smock..Let me check that.

Comment: Added the comments , I tried as suggested, but it's not working

Comment: can you add an `echo Sub \$1: $1` into the Get_Files.sh script to see if the parameter is being passed to it or not?

Comment: Changed it "$1" and it is working manually but not from cron

Comment: do any of the scripts rely on environment variables?

Comment: Thanks Smock I was able to execute that script, there was a silly error i was making at my end.