# script arguments in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, arguments, getopts

I am working on a a script that need to take two script arguments and use them as variables in the script. I couldn't get this working and unable to find out what I am doing wrong. I see the issue is the second argument, as I see in some of my tests(as mentioned in the bottom of this post) it is not being read.

Here is the code:

```
    #!usr/bin/bash


help()
{
   echo ""
    echo "Usage: $0 -p patch_level -e environment"
    echo -e "\t-p Patch level that you are tryin to update the server"
    echo -e "\t-e Environment that the patch need to be run on"
   exit 1 # Exit script after printing help
}


while getopts "p:e" opt
do
   case "${opt}" in
      p ) patch_level="$OPTARG" ;;
      e ) _env="$OPTARG" ;;
      ? ) help ;;    # Print help in case parameter is non-existent

   esac
done


if [ -z "$patch_level" ] || [ -z "$_env" ];    # checking for null parameter
then
   echo "Some or all of the parameters are empty";
   help
else
   echo "$patch_level and $_env"
fi
```

When  I run the script like below , I get this.

```
> ./restart.sh -p 2021 -e sbx 
>  Some or all of the parameters are empty
> Usage: ./restart.sh -p patch_level -e environment
>         -p Patch level that you are tryin to update the server
>         -e Environment that the patch need to be run on
```

Note: I modeled my code based on the third answer in this

[How can I pass a command line argument into a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31414/how-can-i-pass-a-command-line-argument-into-a-shell-script)

I see the issue is with the second variable (-e). Because if I change the last if statement from "or to and", the script runs but doesn't print anything for the second variable:

here is what I am talking about

```
if [ -z "$patch_level" ] && [ -z "$_env" ];
```

the output is

```
./restart.sh -p 2021 -e sbx
  2021 and
 This server will be patched to 2021
```

I am on Ubuntu if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_env` is unset due to how you pass arguments to `getopts`.

You need to add a colon after the `e` to tell `getopts` the option takes an argument.

```
while getopts "p:e:" op
                  ^
              mandatory here
```

Check:

```
help getopts | less
```

Comment: Thanks much. I completely overlooked it. That helped .

I know this is not part of the question but asking anyway. Is there a way , I can accept on certain strings for second argument. for example 

`-e will only take sbx|inf|perf|prod `

Comment: Thanks to post a new question

Comment: @MO12, most usually you'd just add another test later in the script, e.g. `case $_env in sbx|inf|perf|prod) ;; *) exit 1;; esac`

Comment: @ilkkachu thank you